# Use Threads and network machine to handle most of the work using xml-rpc

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, network-programming, xml-rpc

I am designing an application that seems it can be overwelming with certain functions that have to happen. Basically in some part of the application  a conversion has to happen on the local machine in shell scripts that can take a very long time "up to 10 mins" for user objects. So the user wont have to wait to leave the page because the response from the server would take a long time, I was thinking of two approaches that would eliminate that problem.

My idea is that I can create a thread right before that conversion has to happen and make that child thread run the shell scripts while the main thread continues on so the user wouldn't still have a loading screen in front of them **only brainstorming** so not sure how this code would look in C# or if it would give me the idea i actually want, because I only have done multithreading in perl. The process to start the function would be something like this:

```
public void RunShellScripts(string apppath, string fileargs)
{
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = apppath;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = fileargs;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
p.Start();
//after this is done the converted file would be saved in this current directory
//which is the in the value of the fileargs variable
}
```

Also to add to that, so the machine that host the web server wouldn't try to handle so many processes of converting at once, another idea adding on top of that is to have a network machine receive an xml rpc from the web server machine to do the conversion of the file. So basically the webserver receives the objects then sends a xml rpc to the network machine to do the conversion and sends the converted file back to the host machine. I am familar with xml-rpc as well, but not sure if I could have it send a file back. side note the files could be up to 1GB total. My experience has only been sending results and only in a different language then C# as well.

Comment: Consider using a workflow instead. They are meant to be able to pause when idle and then resume later.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all you need is a parallel `Task` that either runs the shell scripts on the local machine or sends an XML-RPC request to a different machine. You can also register a callback to notify the parent thread that the work was completed:

```
SendOrPostCallback callback = o => Console.WriteLine((string) o));
SynchronizationContext context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(
           () =>
           {
               RunShellScripts(); // maybe also parallelize this method
               // or XML-RPC
               context.Post(callback, "Work finished!");
           });
```

Of course, the callback code can be anything, I just printed a message here.

I've worked with XML-RPC a while back but honestly I don't remember very much. I trust you know how to handle that part.

Answer (score 0):

There is usually more than one way to skin a cat :)

A project I am working on with a client of ours recently went live.  Part of that application entails converting documents to tiff.  Since it too is a web-based app there are some similarities to what you are trying to achieve.

However, we used my open-source service bus (http://shuttle.codeplex.com/) although any service bus would do or you could roll something using some queueing mechanism.

What happens is that a file to be converted is copied to some file share.  This is performed through our application service `DocumentConverter.Submit(source, outputMimeType)`.  Then, still part of the application service call, a `ConvertDocumentCommand` command is sent on the service bus.  The command is routed to the converter machine and the caller carries on with whatever it was doing.

The converter endpoint receives the command that contains the pertinent data (such as file name) on the queue and uses the file in the file share to perform the conversion using a third-party converter.  Once the conversion completes the converter endpoint publishes a `DocumentConvertedEvent` or when it fails a `DocumentConversionErrorEvent`.

The sender has an endpoint that subscribes to the two events and the converted document is used if available.  For us the converted document is placed in the ***output*** sub-folder of the file share that the input documents go to.

This may sound somewhat convoluted but it works really well since our converter endpoint is just concerned with converting documents and publishing conversion results.  It is blissfully unaware of *any* other applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to balance the load on another computer, possible answers involves distributed computing and message queues.

### Message Queues

Take a look to RabbitMQ :

Once you have a server running, client can send and receive message : the web server sends the script, the processing server receive a message, then sends another message back.

Here is a "Hello World" in Java : http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html

The C# client docuimentation : https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/tree/master/dotnet

A few other resources about the C# client :

- [Getting Started With RabbitMQ in .net](http://simonwdixon.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/getting-started-with-rabbitmq-in-dotnet/)
- [Using RabbitMQ with C#](http://www.codethinked.com/using-rabbitmq-with-c-and-net)

### Distributed Computing

This might be overkill, but it is scalable. The wikipedia page about [grid computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_computing).

[NGrid](http://ngrid.sourceforge.net/) is a "platform independent grid computing framework written in C#". Here is a [Distributed sort sample](http://ngrid.sourceforge.net/?page=onepagesample). You might distribute the processing on a N nodes grid, then use the result.

### Wcf

I have not used WCF that much, and my few experiences with it were quite annoying. You might delve into this, but I'm not sure it serves your goals.

One link, however, that might be useful in order to tranfer large chunks of data : [How to: Enable Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx)

### Alternatives

Maybe a simple remoting or socket messaging would be enough. Its depends on multiple factors : wanted scalability, computing power, ... But the message queue looks like a path to explore.

I hope you will find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without xml-rpc then you can try the following:

1. Create a thread to start the process of conversion.
2. Wait for the process to exit.
3. Raise an event when the process has finished so that you can carry out any opertaions on the result.

   ```
      //step 1. To create a thread in .Net 2.0 and higher you could use the
      //ParameterizedThreadStart delegate. For example

       Thread t = new Thread (new ParameterizedThreadStart(RunShellScripts));

       Hashtable args = new Hashtable();
   ```

   //you can use any other technique you like to encapsulate the parameters

   ```
   hashtable[1] = apppath;
   hashtable[2] = fileargs;

       t.Start (args);

       static void RunShellScripts(object args)
       {
        //code to start the process
        //step 2. Wait for the process to exit
        while (!shellProcess.HasExited)
        {
           //call sleep (Thread.sleep()) or just do nothing
        }
        //step 3. raise event to notify the end of process.
        //shellProcess.ExitCode can tell you if the process exited with error or not
       }
   ```